# gnuplot time format variable separated by spaces

Tags: time, timestamp, gnuplot

I have a dataset with columns separated by spaces.  The columns are ' year month day hour data ' in this order.

I have tried several time formats such as "%Y%m%d%H", "%Y%m%d%k", "%Y %m %d %k" but they don't work.  I think it is because the columns change the number of digits.

Which is the appropiate time format for this kind of data?

Here's an example of the data set.

```
   2002  12  31   9    65
   2002  12  31  10    60
   2002  12  31  11    56
   2002  12  31  12    50
   2002  12  31  13    45
   2002  12  31  14    38
   2002  12  31  15    45
   2002  12  31  16    50
   2002  12  31  17    47
   2002  12  31  18    44
   2002  12  31  19    40
   2002  12  31  20    32
   2002  12  31  21    35
   2002  12  31  22    40
   2002  12  31  23    33
   2003   1   1   0    28
   2003   1   1   1    25
```

And here's my code:

```
     set xdata time
     set timefmt "%Y%m%d%k"
     plot   "datafile.dat" using 1:2  
     set terminal png enhanced  
     set output "series.png"
     replot
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having spaces in you date is fine, you must only count the column properly: your data is in the fifth column, no matter how many columns are consumed by the timefmt:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y %m %d %H"
plot   "datafile.dat" using 1:5
```

And a single space in the timefmt matches one or more white spaces in the data.